# Robolectric RuntimeException when applying Android style - ShadowAssetManager.buildAttribute

Tags: android, android-styles, robolectric, android-progressbar

I'm trying to build an Activity in Robolectric but it is failing because of a failure to inflate the activity's XML. I've included the offending components below. I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer yet online.

I've tried creating custom Shadow classes, but that did not work (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2155#issuecomment-283890626).

This seems like a basic problem that anyone using the Android attributes would run into, so I'm not really sure what is going wrong here.

```
    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity.class)
            .withIntent(intent)
            .create()
            .get();
```

Below is the XML containing the offending attribute style

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/blocking_progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/cycle" />
```

Below is that stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: no value for android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle in theme with applied styles: [Style android:Theme_DeviceDefault (and parents) (forced), Style com.package.name:Theme_XXX (and parents) (forced)]
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.buildAttribute(ShadowAssetManager.java:463)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowAssetManager.java:532)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:213)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
```

**EDIT**

The following was the solution to my problem, though I still feel like it's a Robolectric bug.

Changing from style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle" to style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small" fixes the problem.

[Robolectric Issue with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302867/robolectric-issue-with-progressbar)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to getting the exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: no value for android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle in theme with applied styles`. The code shown below also works for other views that fail to inflate because no value was found in theme with applied styles.

Step 1) Create a `ShadowTheme` class extending `org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.ShadowTheme`, as seen below:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implementation;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources;

@Implements(value = Resources.Theme.class)
public class ShadowTheme extends ShadowResources.ShadowTheme {


@Implementation
@Override
public TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    try {
        return super.obtainStyledAttributes(set, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    } catch (Throwable err) {
        AttributeSet attributeSet = Robolectric.buildAttributeSet()
                .addAttribute(android.R.attr.layout_width, "0dp")
                .addAttribute(android.R.attr.layout_height, "0dp")
                .build();
        return super.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
}
}
```

Step 2: Add shadow to `@RunWith` shadows annotation value, as seen below:

```
import android.os.Build;
import com.superbalist.android.BuildConfig;
import com.superbalist.android.test.shadow.ShadowTheme;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
    sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1,
    shadows = {ShadowTheme.class})
public class MyUnitTest {

}
```

Comment: I came across this error after applied this solution:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowArscAssetManager9 cannot be cast to class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAssetManager (org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowArscAssetManager9 and org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAssetManager are in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @59f76599)